# What is the point of writing your code with hexadecimal notation for numbers?

Tags: c++, binary, hex

I was just reading a programming book the other day which talked about writing better code. I got to a section which described how to take any binary number and convert it to hexadecimal notation. I'm sort of new to programming and I was wondering what the advantage was of writing out your numbers in hexadecimal notation, or even the binary literal format, over just using the normal base 10 or decimal system? Is it for speed purposes? If so, would there still be an advantage for using the hexadecimal system with C++ even though it's not assembly code?

Comment: You usually use it for when bitwise operations are important, as two hex digits can represent all of the values of a byte.

Comment: Usually it's just convenience. For example, RGB values can be represented by 0xRRGGBB ie 0x235492, 23 is red, 54 is green, 92 is blue. You can't interpret the decimal 2315410 as easily.

Comment: Raw pointers are also easier to read and compare in hexadecimal. On some platforms. patterns in the high bits of an address can provide useful clues as to what the pointer is pointing at (code, data, constant data, hardware buffers, &c); and these are only easily visible in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using direct bit manipulation it is often much more clear, since a single hexidecimal digit maps neatly onto 4 bits. It's easy to see that `0x77` is equal to `0111 0111` in binary, but it's much tougher to see that both of those equal 119. So if you wanted to use this to drop just the bits in positions 0 and 4 for whatever reason, it's a lot easier to see what's going on when you write `0x77 & i` as opposed to `119 & i`.

Answer (score 3):

I find the results of bitwise operators much easier to follow when written in hex or binary than in decimal.

```
255 & 15 = 15

0xFF & 0x0F = 0x0F   // Much easier to follow
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any performance benefit to typing `2` (base 10) vs `0x02` (base 16). Both are constants.

However, I find it most convenient to read/use code performing bitwise operations (e.g., bitmasking) using hexadecimal.

### Contrived Example

```
#include <iostream>

bool isBit2Set(int value)
{
    static const int BIT_2_MASK = 0x02;
    return (value & BIT_2_MASK) != 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " has bit 2 enabled? " << std::boolalpha << isBit2Set(i) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
0 has bit 2 enabled? false
1 has bit 2 enabled? false
2 has bit 2 enabled? true
3 has bit 2 enabled? true
4 has bit 2 enabled? false
5 has bit 2 enabled? false
6 has bit 2 enabled? true
7 has bit 2 enabled? true
8 has bit 2 enabled? false
```